# Error - ndefined method `text_field' for #<Selenium::WebDriver:

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, watir-webdriver, browserstack

Using: Ruby Cucumber Watir
running the following Browser Stack Command line - 
cucumber BS_USERNAME=XXX BS_AUTHKEY=XXX SELENIUM_PLATFORM=WINDOWS SELENIUM_BROWSER=CHROME
The error points to the following line -

@browser.text_field(:id => 'uname').when_present.set 'xxxxxxx'

Note:I tried appending the @browser with @element = @browser. Got the same error. The file structure in Ruby mine appears to be fine. Any insight would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

The exception suggests that `@browser` is a `Selenium::WebDriver::Driver`. To use Watir's `text_field` method, `@browser` needs to be a `Watir::Browser` (or a `Watir::Element`).

You are likely opening the browser with a line like:

```
@browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
```

However, to use Watir, the browser should be opened like:

```
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback ....  made the stated change. I am now using @browser - Watir::Browser.new :chrome.   I now have the error : uninitialized constant Watir (NameError). I made the change in the env.rb  and step def .rb file /

Comment: It sounds like you are missing a `require 'watir'`. Is this a brand new Cucumber test suite or are you trying to migrate an existing Selenium one to Watir?

Comment: I am trying to migrate Selenium to waiter

Comment: I added the require watir as well as other required gems. error:uninitialized constant Watir::WebDriver (NameError)
.is there a way to upload myenv.rb and step file to this discussion ? I don't see that feature  on Stack over flow

Comment: You can just edit the question to include the relevant code. Note that you just need to provide enough code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Justin, you're using method text_field which is not available in selenium webdriver. Use below code to make this work:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I need to convert the ruby selenium to ruby watir-webdriver as you mentions. I changed the notation from Selenium::Webdrive to Watir Webdrive in my env.rb file ......... as provided below

Comment: My  cucumber Step def looks like this ..@browser.goto "https://multi-tenant-dev-1.gridasaservice.com/login?timeout=true"

Comment: The command line that executes the script  Browser ...cucumber BS_USERNAME=kevinclarke2 BS_AUTHKEY=5AyLAPWXEESrJLd3kCM9 SELENIUM_PLATFORM=WINDOWS SELENIUM_BROWSER=CHROME

Comment: Watir-webdriver is amog the installed gems in the project.

Comment: Watir-Webdriver has been moved to Watir. There should be no reason to be using Watir-Webdriver.

Comment: just include code present in your env.rb file in the question.